# Azure connecting to a remote Checkpoint VPN device (4807)

Tags: azure, vpn, checkpoint

We are creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and we would like to deploy in Windows Azure.

However, our application must interact with a remote provider through a (site to site) VPN 
connection to their premises. Their firewall device (I'm not sure if this is the correct term) 
is a Checkpoint 4807 (http://www.checkpoint.com/products/4000-appliances/ seems to have the 
specifications for it). They use 3DES, MD5 and Group 2 DH for IKE Phase 1, and 3DES/ESP and 
MD5 for IKE Phase 2.

**Is there a way we can set up this kind of VPN connection using Windows Azure?** We showed Azure's 
specifications page (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/) to our providers and they said we can't, but we wanted to confirm this.

We're worried we wouldn't be able to use Azure because of this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion over here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wavirtualmachinesvirtualnetwork/thread/b4b8bef1-9546-473a-be84-852e00f3171b) it should be solvable.